# moving specific image from directory to another in python

Tags: python

I want to move a specific image that ends with(label_0.png) from a directory that contains many images to another directory.

my code in python is:

```
import os
import shutil
src = 'ddd/'
des = 'training images/'
for a in os.listdir(file_path):
    if a.endswith('label_0.png'):
        print(a)
        shutil.move(a, des)
```

I get an error :
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'id_1_label_0.png'

Although there are two images that end with (label_0.png) in src folder

I tried to make another directory in another drive like drive E but it is the same problem.
please help me

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enter complete path in the source. Try this:

```
import os
import shutil
src = 'ddd/'
des = 'training images/'
for a in os.listdir(src):
    if a.endswith('label_0.png'):
        srcpath = os.path.join(src,a)
        shutil.move(srcpath, des)
```

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :)